# Change mouse cursor when I mouse down on an object on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I'm developing a web page for my customer.

I wanted to change its cursor icon when a user mousedown on the object.
For instance,

1. there is an image on webpage
2. the user click on the image also its cursor should be changed to "grabbing"
3. the user can drag & drop image position
4. Finally when the user mouse uped, its mouse cursor have to be changed to "default"

I tried these steps above. but I wasn't able to change the cursor when the user mouse downed.

Can JavaScript change mouse cursor on that timing? and How?

By the way I always saw "Change cursor on hover event" but I couldn't find the same situation above.

Comment: sure, probably some CSS will help

Answer (score 0):

If you have html elements you can just use the CSS [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property.

If you really need to use javascript :

```
document.yourSelector.style.cursor = "grabbing";
```

But you shouldn't need to :

```
.yourImages:active { /* When mouse is down */
    cursor:grabbing;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it but I wasn't able to change the mouse cursor when I mouse downed. However, I have confirmed changed the cursor when I mouse up. Probably the internet browser didn't react "change cursor" until I mouse up. Hm.. It's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

use the [:active pseudo-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

```css
.img:active {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150,jpg" class="img">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it but I wasn't able to change the mouse cursor when I mouse downed. While I mouse down, Can the browser not change the cursor?